# How to write query with not equal to <!=> in where condition?

Tags: mysql, yii2

I need to fetch data from the table and send bulk sms to the customers,to send the sms , the contact number is stored in a variable,i use for each and get the numbers,i manually enter the id and fetching the data , now i need to collect all the datas by giving where 'id'!='o',in query so i will get all the numbers.

Now I am manually giving the id number in where condition just like

```
where(['idsmsdata' => [1,6,7]]);
```

my query is:

```
$query1 = (new \yii\db\Query())->select(['number'])
                                ->from('smsdata')
                                ->where(['idsmsdata' => [1,6,7]]);
$command1 = $query1->createCommand();
$data1 = $command1->queryAll();
$vnumber = '';
foreach($data1 as $row1) {
    $vnumber .= $row1['number'].',' ;
}
echo $vnumber;
```

I will get an output in  $vnumber as :96xxxxxx,85xxxxxxx,77xxxxxxx. 
the three corresponding number in the id's.

I expect the query to be as where id != 0 , so that it can fetch the remaining ids.

Comment: If you want ALL rows then just REMOVE the limiting factors in the where clause. In other words just remove that limitation completely

Comment: So just remove `->where(['idsmsdata' => [1,6,7]]` from that query

Comment: yes its working...!

Comment: Of course it is :)

Comment: how to delete this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first queue can be done as follows:

```
$query1 = (new \yii\db\Query())->select(['number'])
                                ->from('smsdata')
                                ->where(['idsmsdata' => [1,6,7]])
                                ->all();
$vnumber = '';
foreach($data1 as $row1) {
    $vnumber2 .= $row1['number'].',' ;
}
```

**Get all the rows**:

```
$query1 = (new \yii\db\Query())->select(['number'])
                                ->from('smsdata')
                                ->all();
$vnumber2 = '';
foreach($data1 as $row1) {
    $vnumber2 .= $row1['number'].',' ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$query1 = (new \yii\db\Query())->select(['number'])
                                ->from('smsdata')
                                ->where(['<>','idsmsdata', 0]);

$command1 = $query1->createCommand();
$data1 = $command1->queryAll();
$vnumber = '';
foreach($data1 as $row1) {
    $vnumber .= $row1['number'].',' ;
}
echo $vnumber;
```